# Editing an alert dialog inside an on-click listener

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

The following alert dialog has a title and four items (i.e red, green, blue and black). I would like to change the icon every time one of these items is selected.

Here's my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black"};

alertDialog.setTitle("Pick a color");

alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int num) {
        switch(num) {
            case 0: alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.red);
            break;

            case 1: alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.green);
            break;

            case 2: alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.blue);
            break;

            case 3: alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.black);
            break;
            }
    }
});
```

I can attest to the fact that the .setIcon() methods are being called; however there are no changes made to the aesthetics of the alert dialog. Effectively, the icon is not being changed even though the correct method is executed.

Can someone please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting icon to `AlertDialog` builder, but should to AlertDialog itself.
Change:

```
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.XxX);
```

to:

```
((AlertDialog)arg0).setIcon(R.drawable.XxX);
```

Comment: I have changed alertDialog to ((AlertDialog)arg0) but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: what is inside R.drawable.red?

Comment: R.drawable.red contains a reference to red.png image. This reference is correct because alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.red); works if its placed right after alertDialog.setTitle("Pick a color");